# TCL script to regroup csv file data

Tags: csv, scripting, tcl

I am new to tcl scripting.

I have 2 columns in my CSV file.

**Example: My data**

```
A 12
D 18
B 33
A 11
D 49
```

I would like to extract column 2 values using Column 1 data.

**Required output:**

```
A: 12,11
B: 33
D: 18, 49
```

Can someone please help me to write a tcl script to perform this task?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very well known problem, and Tcl's `dict lappend` is exactly the tool you need to solve it (together with `csv::split` from tcllib to do the parsing of your input data).

```
package require csv

# Read split and collect
set data {}
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    lassign [csv::split $line] key value; # You might need to configure this
    dict lappend data $key $value
}

# Write out
puts ""; # Blank header line
dict for {key values} $data {
    puts [format "%s: %s" $key [join $values ", "]]
}
```

The above is written as a stdin-to-stdout filter. Adapting to work with files is left as an exercise.

Comment: I assume you want consistent separators in the output. It's hard to imagine not wanting that, but if you do, you'll need to provide a rule (or rules) for choosing them. But it's a lot more work so I advise being consistent!

Comment: If you want the output to also be CSV, use `csv::join`. The requirements as written don't seem to ask for that.